# Saving and retrieving inherited types with LINQtoSQL and Business Objects

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, inheritance, orm, single-table-inheritance

I have an abstract EventBase class and some inherited event types, along with an Event class.  Each event type has its own unique columns.

In my data layer, I have a GetEvents method that simply does:

```
from e in db.Events
    select new Event {...values...};
```

EventType is an enum which matches up to an EventTypes table

I want GetEvents(EventType type) and GetEvent(int id, EventType type) to do something like..

```
from e in GetEvents()
    where e.TypeId == (int)type
    select new TypeSpecified {...values for Event + Type-specific fields...};

// Determine what type it is
// Switch statement? Dictionary?
```

I'm not sure a switch is the best idea, but I'm also not sure how to correctly employ a dictionary to map the data retrieval and object creation to a specific type.

My second question involves saving the data - going from Business Object to L2S table - same question as above, basically

I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Are you already using single table inheritance? IE have you defined a single table with all possible columns, plus a discriminator column that identifies the type of each row? It's hard to answer your question without knowing whether you're using that already or not.

Answer (score 1):

The page from Rick Strahl helpped me to get my business layer up and running. This might be a good start for you too.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/160237.aspx

My main problem was that I tend to over engineer the business layer. So one have to keep it simple but not to simple ;-)